# Mostrar formulario de registro nuevo devise aun estando logeado

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

estoy trabajando con la Gema devise para la autenticación de usuarios en mi aplicación, pero tengo la siguiente duda, yo puedo crear usuarios sin aver ingresado al sistema, pero ¿Cómo logro hacer para registrarlos cuando este logeado? (Me muestre el formulario) y no me salte el cartel que ya estoy identificado.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: En este [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075873/devise-how-to-create-a-new-user-being-already-logged-in) puede estar tu solución

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar mi problema, cree las vistas,el controlador user, y en el modelo, quite el :registerable, agregue los parámetros correspondientes al controlador y ya estoy registrando nuevos usuarios en el sistema.

Answer (score 1):

Usar la gema activeadmin es una muy buena opcion para hacer eso, lo otro que puedes hacer es correr un seed con User.create(parametros) lo puedes iterar en un .times cuantas veces desees luego rake db:seed y walaa tienes varios usuarios

Comment: Ya conocía activeadmin, pero mi experiencia no fué lo que esperaba... Lo que quiero es manejar el nivel de permisos mediante el registro de un nuevo usuario, esto parte desde que ingreso al sistema, obviamente teniendo los privilegios correspondientes para agregar un usuario a la aplicación.

Comment: genera una vista form para crear usuarios(agrega los parametros que quieras para el create dale una revisada como es el form de registration de devise app/view/devise/registration si no me equivoco) esta vista que en su controlador tenga un before_action: user.admin true, previo antes genera una tabla a user de admin:bolean, con cancancan puedes hacer roles de usuarios tambien por rails c crea un admin true y walaa deberias poder crear usuarios sin problemas te recomiendo usar ajax a modo de practica :) !

Comment: Ya pude realizarlo. Gracias por las respuestas de ayuda.